Shannon Capacity Law Equation
Which one is the correct shanon capacity law equation? 
Or :  
Thank you for helping,

High schooler

Hi Youssef, advice for a High schooler: Always cite your sources (i.e,. state where something is from). Not only do we actively expect you to, it's also a very important hint for the reader to learn about the context in which something is said. This would help you here a lot. You'll find the upper thing is from a presentation about something involving MIMO.

In your case, the upper formula describes something with a multi-input multi-output channel (otherwise, there would be no "Channel matrix") and operated for a certain time (T falls out of nowhere!).

So, while both use the letter "C" to describe something, the upper formula describes something else than the capacity of a simple noisy channel. The encyclopedia definition from your second source is the right one. You need to be careful which sources you read: Context matters!

@MarcusMüller Thank you for your advice and help!!

Always cite your sources (i.e,. state where something is from). Not only do we actively expect you to, it's also a very important hint for the reader to learn about the context in which something is said. This would help you here a lot. You'll find the upper thing is from a presentation about something involving MIMO.
In your case, the upper formula describes something with a multi-input multi-output channel (otherwise, there would be no "Channel matrix") and operated for a certain time (T falls out of nowhere!).
So, while both use the letter "C" to describe something, the upper formula describes something else than the capacity of a simple noisy channel. The encyclopedia definition from your second source is the right one. You need to be careful which sources you read: Context matters!
So, the lower formula $C=B\log_2(1+ S/N)$ is the Shannon Capacity. It's literally from Shannon's 1949 paper, Communication in the Presence of Noise. You'll find this exact formula in there, using $W$ where you use $B$ – but letters aren't important, it's what these symbols stand for!
So, that's the takeaway here:

the lower formula is what you're looking for
it's more important to understand in which situation you're in than that you know a formula by heart

This binary Shannon Capacity describes the maximum rate at which you can transport bits through a channel while making as little errors as you want (so, approaching "no errors at all"), if that channel gives you, at its output, what you put into it, added to some noise that is independent of what you put in.
Anyways, if you're a high schooler, this is a very impressive formula! And it's impressive to be able to work with it and explain what it's for. So, you go and be proud of what you're doing!
